# Cakephp (2.x) Model Validation using "onclick" in Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a code already wrote... in CakePHP. 
And, I've add some model validations.

But, in Jquery, this code works fine (model validation and HTML5 messages):

```
$('#itemAdd').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $itemAdd = $("#itemAdd");
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.serialize();

    $.ajax({
         ...
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
                    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                });
                location.reload();
            }
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error");
    });

});
```

But, when it's using 'click', the ajax method works but the validation NOT... :( :

```
$("#next-item").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $itemAdd = $("#itemAdd");
        var data = $itemAdd.serializeArray();
        var $this = $(this);

        $.ajax({
        ... 
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
                alert('go !');
                var $addItem = $("#addItem");
                $addItem.removeData('modal-header');
                $addItem.removeData('modal-body');
                $("#addItem .modal-content").load('<?php echo FULL_BASE_URL; ?>/stock/stocks/modal_item_add/<?php echo $batch_id; ?>', function () {
                    $('#addItem').modal('show');
                });
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An error :  " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown  );
        });

            return false;
    });
```

The validation based on the Model doesn't work. But, in the Php method ,launched with Jquery Ajax, show me (it's ok) the validations errors with :

```
$this->Item->invalidFields();
```

There's a problem cause when I use *$("#next-item")* I want the jQuery modal not hide.
And using "submit" instead of "click" close the modal.

Can anybody has an idea ?

Thanks.
F.

Comment: I'm unsure what this has to do with CakePHP. It appears to be a javascript/jquery issue only.

Comment: ok. But why I've not a JS/JQ error ?. If I add/remove rules in the model's file, the validation working/not working : fine, it's ok. But the HTML/JS is "taking avantage above" the cakePHP rules :(. Have you a fonctionnal example ?. thanks.